# Can not create pdf file in matlab

Tags: matlab, pdf

I am running the following script to create pdf file.

```
%% Plotting confusion matrix
if(opt == 1)
    plotconfusion_mod(y(:,1:2)',y(:,3:4)');
elseif(opt == 2)
    plotconfusion_mod(y(:,1:4)',y(:,5:8)');
elseif(opt == 3)
    plotconfusion_mod(y(:,1:10)',y(:,11:20)');
    set(gcf,'position',[100, -100, 800, 800])
end
set(gcf,'Units','inches'); screenposition = get(gcf,'Position');
set(gcf,'PaperPosition',[0 0 screenposition(3:4)],'PaperSize',screenposition(3:4));

%% Saving
Q = input('Do you want to save the results (Y/N)\n','s');
if(Q == 'y' || Q == 'Y')
    print(1,['confusion_matrix_' num2str(opt)],'-dpdf','-r512');
else
    return
end
```

But I am getting the following error on Windows operating system.

```
Error using name (line 102)
Cannot create output file '.\snippet_1.pdf'.

Error in print (line 85)
    pj = name( pj );
```

Can anyone help with it please?

The value of opt is 1.

Comment: Can you confirm that saving the variable y works by inserting this into your code right before the print ? save('y','y')
If it creates y.mat then that would confirm that you do not have any writing permission issues.

Comment: Error using save
Unable to write file y: permission denied.
Getting permission denied.
How can I give permission? @sg1234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the comments, the problem is due to the OP accessing a directory without permissions. Several answers might be appropriate in this case but likely require knowing more about the system (Linux, Windows, Mac, which directory, etc.). However, I feel like the easiest way to avoid such hassles is to simply move your code into a sub-directory that is in your HOME directory.

HOME directory might mean different things depending on your system, but it is usually the one that contains your "documents" folder.

If you do not want to move the codebase for some reason, you wil require assistance with changing permissions and are best off asking in system-specific forum or with system-specific tags.

Comment: You are right. I fixed my issue by changing the directory. Thanks a lot @sg1234